# How can I alter this script to allow voting once per day?

Tags: php, mysql, vote

I'm trying to incorporate the script in this tutorial [appreciate badge tutorial](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/07/click-to-appreciate-badge-ajax-jquery-css/)

but I would like to be able to allow the IP to vote once per day. could anyone offer a suggestion on altering the code?

cheers

Comment: What you want can be thought about logically - then work out the technical steps one by one ...

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

Check for the existance of the users IP address in the table with a simple query - then if the entries date is within the last 24 hours dont allow ... simple ...

Comment: right the idea is simple, however the script I've chosen to use (out of time restraint) is slightly more complicated.... had anyone looked at the code for the tutorial before posting?

Comment: yes - i looked at the code - and gave my answer - i told you exactly how to approach it - that is what you asked for

Comment: i appreciate the input but as I am just learning PHP I am working through other code to understand how it all works...
I get the logic behind what needs to happen, I'm just having trouble making it work
My issue is how to 'phrase' for instance 'if the entries date is within the last 24 hours, don't allow' That is what I was looking for help with

Answer (score 0):

Update the table definition of `appreciate_votes` and add a column `appreciated_on` to store the timestamp.
Update the where clause of the query on line 77 with `DATEDIFF(now(),appreciated_on)>1`

*This has not been tested.*

Answer (score 0):

A quick and simple way would be to add a field that had a datatype of `DATE` and add a unique index on that field and your IP field. That way the database will only allow entry per IP + Date combination.

Make sure you change the inserts to `INSERT IGNORE` so you don't get mysql errors upon insertion.